# Facebook login not working for the first time - ios

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift2, fbsdk

I have Facebook SDK integrated into my ios application. This is the code I use:

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Browser
loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], fromViewController: context, handler: {(result, error) -> Void in
    //My handling code
})
```

When I try to login with facebook for the first time, after installing the app, it goes through my code just fine but nothing happens - browser doesn't appear and handler doesn't fire, there's no error and there's nothing in logs. After that, it works every time I try to login, even after I force-quit the app.

I'm not really sure, if this problem appeared because of something I did, or if it was the problem from the first day.

Comment: is loginManager object global or it is in method only?

Comment: It's created in the method.

Comment: can you try by making it global?

Comment: Wow, it actually works, thanks. If you write it as an answer, I can accept it. You think it didn't work because manager wasn't initialized in time?

Comment: Great! yes, most probably the reason is same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try by making `loginManager` object global.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for this answer.